# Make conditional relation on mysql tables using Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have tables like below.

**Table A**

```
id  | val_a
1   | a1
2   | a2
3   | a3
```

**Table B**

```
id  | id_a| val_b | resource_type
1   | 2   | b1    |  1
2   | 2   | b2    |  2
3   | 3   | b3    |  3
4   | 3   | b4    |  3
```

**Table Resource_A**

```
id  |r_val| id_b
1   | ra1 | 1
```

**Table Resource_B**

```
id  |r_val| id_b
1   | rb1 | 2
```

**Table Resource_C**

```
id  |r_val| id_b
1   | rc1 | 3
2   | rc2 | 4
```

If `resource_type` is 1 in Table `B`, then table `B` make relation with table `Resource_A`.

If `resource_type` is 2 in Table `B`, then table `B` make relation with table `Resource_B`.

If `resource_type` is 3 in Table `B`, then table `B` make relation with table `Resource_C`.

**Required Output is:**

```
id_b | id_a| val_b |val_a | resource_type| r_val
 1   | 2   | b1    |  a1  |    1         | ra1 
 2   | 2   | b2    |  a2  |    2         | rb1 
 3   | 3   | b3    |  a3  |    3         | rc1 
 4   | 3   | b4    |  a3  |    3         | rc2
```

**But what is the best way to get it without using loop in laravel?**

**How Can I achieve this by using Laravel 5.2 OR Laravel 4 OR PHP OR MYSQL Query?**

Thanks Ahead.

Comment: I think you have a slight typo in your expected output.  `val_a` should never have a value of `a1`, because its corresponding `id_a` value never appears in the B table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to join the tables together as I have done below.  The tricky part here is bringing in the correct `r_val` from the three resource tables.  We can do this by left joining to each resource table, and then using the following expression to grab the matching value:

```
COALESCE(t1.r_val, t2.r_val, t3.r_val) AS r_val
```

This will take the first non `NULL` value from a resource table, in order of left to right.  Assuming that each ID from `tableb` only appears once, in one of the resource tables, the order of the terms inside `COALESCE()` should not matter.

```
SELECT tb.id AS id_b,
       tb.id_a,
       tb.val_b,
       COALESCE(ta.val_a, 'NA') AS val_a,
       tb.resource_type,
       COALESCE(t1.r_val, t2.r_val, t3.r_val) AS r_val
FROM tableb tb
LEFT JOIN tablea ta
    ON tb.id_a = ta.id
LEFT JOIN resource_a t1
    ON tb.id = t1.id_b
LEFT JOIN resource_b t2
    ON tb.id = t2.id_b
LEFT JOIN resource_c t3
    ON tb.id = t3.id_b
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen